# Cloud Firestore: text search

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find users by `Europe/Chisinau` timezone. An example of such a user:

```
'device':{
    'from':'{"status":"success","country":"Moldova","countryCode":"MD","zip":"MD-3300","timezone":"Europe/Chisinau"}'
}
```

Here the `from` field is a string. Here's what I've tried using:

```
In [1]: from google.cloud import firestore
   ...: firestore_client = firestore.Client.from_service_account_json('creds.json')
   ...: ref = firestore_client.collection('databases').document('testing')
In [2]: ref.collection(u'users').where(u'device.from', u'>=', u'Europe/Chisinau').where(u'device.from', u'<=', u'Europe/Chisinau').get()
Out[2]: []
```

As you can see, I got an empty list. I have used this [module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `from` field is a single string value, in which you've encoded a JSON object. You won't be able to query individual parts of the JSON object in such a case, as Firestore can only search from the start of the string. So this may work:

```
ref.collection(u'users').where(u'device.from', u'>=', u'{"status":"success"').where(u'device.from', u'<=', u'{"status":"updated"')
```

The above may work, because it's what the `from` field starts with. But you cannot search for values in other part of the string.

---

If you want to be able to search the individual parts of your JSON object, consider storing it as a map instead of a string:

```
'device':{
  'from': {
    "status": "success",
    "country":"Moldova",
    "countryCode":"MD",
    "zip":"MD-3300",
    "timezone":"Europe/Chisinau"
  }
}
```

Now you can perform the query with:

```
ref.collection(u'users').where(u'device.from.timezone', u'==', u'Europe/Chisinau')
```

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for your reply. This works, but I also got users with Europe/Kiev timezone. And I don't see you specifying the timezone when making a request. 
That is, how can I search for users in a different time zone, for example US/Alaska?

Comment: I hope that it's clear from my answer why your current query can never work: the data is simply not in a format that can be queried, as you're trying to filter by the end of a string, which Firestore doesn't support. After converting the JSON string to a map, the data is in the right format, and I merely rewrote your condition to use an `==` instead of two range conditions. If you're still having problems after all that, I recommend posting. new question with the updated data structure, and the query you're firing.